# Relay: Optimistic update not causing a component rerender

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

I'm using PostgraphQL (https://github.com/calebmer/postgraphql) with Relay and wired a UpdateQuestionMutation into my app. However, I do not get optimistic updating to work.
(When I enable network throttling in chrome I can see that the the optimistic update gets handled but the component still shows the old title).
Do I miss something? I have following pieces :

```
class QuestionClass extends Component<IQuestion, void> {

save = (item) => {
    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
        new UpdateQuestionMutation({store: this.props.store, patch: item})
    );
    this.isEditing = false;
};

public render(): JSX.Element {
    const item = this.props.store;
    console.log(item);
```

...

```
const Question = Relay.createContainer(QuestionClass, {
    fragments: {
        // The property name here reflects what is added to `this.props` above.
        // This template string will be parsed by babel-relay-plugin.
        store: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on Question {
                ${UpdateQuestionMutation.getFragment('store')}
                title
                description
                userByAuthor {
                    ${User.getFragment('store')}
                }
            }`,
    },
});
```

...

```
export default class UpdateQuestionMutation extends Relay.Mutation<any, any> {
    getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL `mutation { updateQuestion }`
    }

    getVariables() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return {
            id: this.props.store.id,
            questionPatch: this.props.patch
        }
    }

    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL `fragment on UpdateQuestionPayload { question }`
    }

    getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type: "FIELDS_CHANGE",
            fieldIDs: {
                question: this.props.store.id
            }
        }]
    }

    getOptimisticResponse() {
        return {
            store: this.props.patch
        }
    }

    // This mutation has a hard dependency on the question's ID. We specify this
    // dependency declaratively here as a GraphQL query fragment. Relay will
    // use this fragment to ensure that the question's ID is available wherever
    // this mutation is used.
    static fragments = {
        store: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on Question {
            id
          }
        `,
    };
}
```

Edit: That's what I see in the postgraphql logs:
`mutation UpdateQuestion($input_0: UpdateQuestionInput!) { updateQuestion(input: $input_0) { clientMutationId ...F1 } } fragment F0 on Question { id rowId title description userByAuthor { id rowId username } } fragment F1 on UpdateQuestionPayload { question { id ...F0 } }`

Comment: Just noticed that the component is not rerendered when the optimistic update is through but only when the mutation is through. Do I have to configure relay that is rerenders component

Comment: Can you show an actual query response for the update mutation?

Comment: I am also confused by `store`/`question`. Why are they not named the same? Do they differ?

Comment: I'm not sure which things refer to each other. Does my QuestionReactClass gets the OptimisticResponse as prop? But my UpdateQuestionPayload expects { clientMutationId: String, question: Question, userByAuthor: User, query: Query }